# Loop through xml files in a directory and import specific tag data per file into spreadsheet

Tags: xml, vba, loops, import

I extracted the filename and filepath of all of my xml files in a directory.

I want to loop through each row, find the file in the directory and extract the xml data relative to that file and place the data in the third column of the same row.

Below is code that requires me to select the file I want to search each time. I want my loop routine to do this relative to the criteria in my spreadsheet.

```vb
Dim fd As Office.FileDialog
Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)

With fd

    If .Show = True Then
    
        xmlFileName = .SelectedItems(1)
        
        'Process the file
        Dim fDoc As Object
        Set xDoc = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument")
        xDoc.async = False: xDoc.validateOnParse = False
        xDoc.Load (xmlFileName)
        
        'Get Root Node
        Set Products = xDoc.DocumentElement
        row_number = 1
        For Each Product In Products.ChildNodes
        
            Debug.Print Product.ChildNodes(0).text
            'Debug.Print "<InvoiceNumber>:" & Product.ChildNodes(0).text
            'Debug.Print "<PurchaseOrderNumber>:" & Product.ChildNodes(0).text
            Debug.Print "----------------------"
            
            'Application.Range("ProdutsRange").Cells(row_number, 10).Value = Product.ChildNodes(1).text
            'Application.Range("ProdutsRange").Cells(row_number, 2).Value = Product.ChildNodes(2).text
            'Application.Range("ProdutsRange").Cells(row_number, 3).Value = Product.ChildNodes(3).text
            
            row_number = row_number + 1
            
        Next Product
    End If
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick example to select multiple files and loop through the list:

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub test()
    Dim fd As Office.FileDialog
    Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
    
    With fd
        .AllowMultiSelect = True
        .InitialFileName = "C:\Temp"
        
        If .Show Then
            Debug.Print "You picked " & .SelectedItems.Count & " files"
            Debug.Print "These files are..."
            
            Dim filename As Variant
            For Each filename In .SelectedItems
                Debug.Print "  -- " & filename
                
                '--- process each XML file here
                
            Next filename
        Else
            Debug.Print "You hit cancel"
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```